# ElasticSearch: Match all tokens except stopwords

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an issue defining my mapping using ElasticSearch, let me explain:

I have a list of countries ("France", "United States", "United Kingdom", ...) and I want to be able to search them with or without stopwords. This is what I want:

1. "In France" => **France**
2. "The United States" => **United States**
3. "United" => *nothing*
4. "Pirates in France" => *nothing*

I tried the whitespace analyzer + stopwords filter, but then when I type "united" I get "united states" and "united kingdom", where I expect none of those (see example n°3 above)

I then tried the "keyword" tokenizer to keep "United States" in one token but then I can't filter the stopwords...

Do you know a solution? :)

Comment: don't get you why keyword tokenizer couldn't filter stopwords? to me it looks completely ok

Comment: I believe I do yes; I think it is because if I use the keyword tokenizer, the string "The United States" is interpreted as a single token, which is therefore not filtered as it is no a stopword in itself.